# Webmatrix - Conditional database changes?

Tags: razor, webmatrix

So i have an issue, where that properties on my website are either active or inactive. A property is deemed as inactive by default, and i want it to only become active once it has met some criteria. For example, i only want it to become active when a description is provided, at least one rate has been applied, and only when it has a valid ZIP code assigned.

How would i achieve this, since a user might not populate all this information upon first registration, and may want to come back at a later date to finish updating before it becomes active.

The only way i can think of, is to run an "if" statement, each time i update information on a property, which i can work with, but i was wondering if there was any other conditional way of making this happen, where the database regularly checks to see if should set something to active?

Thanks, Gavin

Comment: I would do it when updating data that relates to the property.

Comment: Agree with Mike. You either have to set the data every time you update it, or use it as criteria every time you read it. It's much more likely to be able to centralise your code and follow DRY principles by adding the logic to your edit code.

Comment: If it makes it any easier, your database entry can also have an `isActive` "bit" property that you adjust to true or false when updating the data (if that wasn't what Mike was already talking about). That way, when reading the database, you simply have to check that value.

Answer (score 1):

If you were running a full version of SQL Server, you could accomplish this with a trigger and a bitflag column like VoidKing suggested.  On the save the trigger would trigger and you would write a complex sql statement that test if all the needed fields are filled and set the bitflag to true or false depending.

I did something like this in a simpler way by having two save buttons.  A "save" that didn't trigger any validation and a "Save and Release" button that applied validation to all the needed fields.  Both buttons saved the data, but the save and release button would only save if the validation passed and it would save the bitfield "isActive" to 1 where the other save method would save it as a 0.

Might be a good approach else you are left with your checking logic on the single save button, which isn't a bad way to go either.

Comment: Would using a computed field be another solution? It might be a bit slower, so could be a concern if speed was paramount, but it means you don't have two sets of data for the same thing that is your job to synchronise - your bit field would only exist as a representation of the underlying data.